# how to delete exe file MAINICON

Tags: delphi, winapi, resources

How can I delete the MAINICON resource entry in exe file(s)? Instead of changing the main icon of a given exe file, I want to delete the main icon, thus, it takes the default windows exe icon. I already know that this API function ***UpdateResource*** can change the MAINICON ( actually can change any resource) but how to delete resource?

Thanks,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`UpdateResource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648049%28VS.85%29.aspx) can add, modify and delete a resource.

> If *lpData* is NULL and *cbData* is 0, the specified resource is deleted from the file indicated by *hUpdate*.